# migrate from DocsList to DriveApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm new to google scripts and was able to manipulate some code to work for a project, but it will no longer work as a result of the following:

```
ReferenceError: "DocsList" is not defined.Dismiss
```

Here is the code I have:

```
function report() {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder("FOLDER NAME HERE");
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var data;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.appendRow(["URL", "Employer"]);
  for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    file = contents[i];
    var qaDate,qaERName
    if (file.getFileType()==DocsList.FileType.SPREADSHEET) {
      var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("data");
      var configSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("Config");
```

I have a few references to DocsList, I've done some digging and cant figure out how to get something similar to getfolder

Comment: Also see other posts, like [migrating-from-docslist-to-driveapp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179429/migrating-from-docslist-to-driveapp?rq=1) and this post:  [how-to-update-docslist-to-driveapp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777164/how-to-update-docslist-to-driveapp-in-my-code)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the first line:

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolder("FOLDER NAME HERE");
```

If you go to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app), and look at all the methods for `DriveApp` that have anything to do with folders, you'll see four methods:

- getFolderById(id)
- getFolders()
- getFoldersByName(name)
- getRootFolder()

There is only one method that will get just one folder, `getFolderById(id)`.  If you are getting the same folder every time, and you can easily get the ID, then use that option.  If that is not possible, then you can use `getFoldersByName(name)`, but that gets multiple folders.  Even though it gets multiple folders, you can easily get just the first folder.

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Folder Name');
var folder = folders.next();

Logger.log('folder: ' + folder.getName());
```

So, start there, and make that change.